# Json schema validation in Golang with gojsonschema

Tags: go, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I am using [gojsonschema](https://github.com/xeipuuv/gojsonschema) library in golang for validating json. How can I get custom error message?

Currently, I get default errors like this:

- productId.Age: Must be greater than or equal to 10

```json
"Age":{
  "type":"number",
  "minimum": 10,
  "messages": {
    "minimum": "This person is too young"
  }
}
```

I'm expecting "This person is too young" custom error. How can I achieve this ? Thanks !

Comment: The library you are using does not use the `messages` property to translate error messages: https://github.com/xeipuuv/gojsonschema/blob/b076d39a02e5015af0a2a96636e4cc479ecd9f45/validation.go#L729

Comment: Is there any workaround to customize errors with this or any other library?

Answer (score 0):

You can catch the error thrown by json schema and customize your exceptions handlers
Encapsulate your validation and capture the errors generated by it, thus assembling your body for response